# How to Assign a JPQL query to a simple Java object?

Tags: sql, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I need to assign the result of a jpql result to a simple class java object

I have something like this

```
class myObject() {
@id
private Long id;
private String Name;
private String description;
...
//getters and setters
}
```

I need to somehow to store the result of this SQL query, example

// could be anytable
    SELECT DISTINCT c.table_id, c.name, NULL AS description FROM anyTable

How do I do this in JPQL and then assign the result to my object?

Comment: You should really try to explain in plain english what you're trying to do (and also work on the quality of the code snippet you're showing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is extremely unclear. So here is a vague answer:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPu");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();    
Query q = em.createQuery("select f.id, f.name from Foo f");
List<Object[]> foos = (List<Object([]>)q.getResultList();

MyObject o = new MyObject();
o.setFoos(foos);
```

Comment: sorry about that, you got it, that was i need for
my problem is that i'm just starting with JPA and JPQL and JavaEE in general, so it's very confusing sometimes
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @ErVeY No problem, I was just saying that as a general advice as you will probably get better/faster answers if the problem is clear (and I was a bit guessing here). Anyway, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's the answer!

```
SELECT NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight)
FROM 
  People AS c;
```

And it's a constructor of entities.PersonWell class:

```
public PersonWell(Integer peopleId, String name, short age, short height, short weight, short speechspeed) {
        this.peopleId = peopleId;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.speechspeed = speechspeed;
    }
```

There's some code for an extraction of result:

```
List<PersonWell> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I hope, It'll help you! :)